How to install support brackets for solar panels on a TPO membrane roof
Replacing a low pitch bitumen roof over a two-car garage with a TPO (0.060) membrane roof.
An existing metal railing is lag-bolted through the roofing into the joists. This railing runs around the perimeter of the roof.
How best to waterproof the mechanical connection point at the railing and the TPO membrane  roof?
The TPO will be glued to tapered ISO board that tapers from the outer edges to a drain in the center of the roof.
Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
